# Grouping Results Without Aggregation In Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping

Short of using aggregation, is there any way to group results by a given field in Elastic Search?

At the moment I have an index with products (one product per document).

I would like to be able to group products by their UPC code if there are multiple products with matching UPC codes. Is this only possible with aggregation?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear since grouping == aggregation which makes this question sound like: "can I do aggregations without using aggregations?"

Comment: You can't group results without aggregations!

Comment: I guess the answer is: "no, you need to do aggregation"?

Comment: Yes that's the answer.

Comment: Given the example I gave above, should I restructure my index to already account for the clustering of results by UPC code (maybe using child documents or something), or should I just use aggregation?

Comment: that could be a good approach! are you trying to do that to deal with the pagination problem in aggregations?

Comment: Well, my issue is that I currently already have a fair bit of aggregation in place. If I now add a top layer of aggregation on top of everything, it would greatly increase the complexity of my query (I think).

The downside to creating a new index is: I will have to restructure my entire index/query to deal with this clustering...  however, that might be the best option...